# How can i select all field of literal control?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

i am  implementing literal control to bind SharePoint list data.

When I select all data  in Literal Control using checkbox in corner then it will select only 10 items of list instead of selecting all items.

How can I select all data of literal control?

I have done code for this but its not working..

[image]

```
var table = $('.ms-listviewtable').DataTable();
$('.ms-listviewtable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
    debugger;
    if ($(this).hasClass('ms-vb-itmcbx')) {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('s4-itm-selected')) {
            $(this).context.parentNode.cells['0'].children['0'].checked = false;
            $(this).parent().removeClass('s4-itm-selected');

        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().addClass('s4-itm-selected');
            $(this).context.parentNode.cells['0'].children['0'].checked = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('s4-itm-selected')) {
            //$(this).context.parentNode.cells['0'].children['0'].checked = false;
            //$(this).parent().removeClass('s4-itm-selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.s4-itm-selected').removeClass('s4-itm-selected');
            $('.ms-listviewtable input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
            $(this).parent().addClass('s4-itm-selected');
            $(this).context.parentNode.cells['0'].children['0'].checked = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please give some proper explanation of your question so one can better understand your problem.